# removeUbiquitousContentAndPersistentStoreAtURL "Must pass in a store name" error using Magical Record

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud, magicalrecord

so I'm successfully using Magical Record with my Core Data/iCloud app.
Here's how I initialize it:

```
- (NSString *) iCloudContainerID {

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"iCloud.%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];
}

- (NSString *) localStoreName {

    return @"test.sqlite";
}

- (NSString *) iCloudContentNameKey {

    return @"test";
}

- (void) setupCoreDataWithiCloud {

    NSString *containerID = [self iCloudContainerID];
    DDLogiCloud(@"Setting up Core Data with iCloud");
    [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithiCloudContainer:containerID
                                          contentNameKey:[self iCloudContentNameKey]                // Must not contain dots
                                         localStoreNamed:[self localStoreName]
                                 cloudStorePathComponent:@"Documents/CloudLogs"     // Subpath within your ubiquitous container that will contain db change logs
                                              completion:^{
                                                  // This gets executed after all the setup steps are performed
                                                  // Uncomment the following lines to verify
                                                  NSLog(@"%@", [MagicalRecord currentStack]);
                                                  // NSLog(@"%i events", [Event countOfEntities]);
                                              }];
}
```

Using the code above correctly sets up Core Data and iCloud.  Along with some notification handlers I'm able to add records locally to core data and the changes are propagated to other devices through iCloud.

During Testing it would be nice to programmatically reset everything.  This is the routine I've been trying to reset CoreData/iCloud based on Apples Docs:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/UsingCoreDataWithiCloudPG/UsingSQLiteStoragewithiCloud/UsingSQLiteStoragewithiCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013491-CH3-SW33

```
 - (bool) resetCoreDataWithiCloud {


        NSString *containerID = [self iCloudContainerID];
        NSURL *cloudURL = [NSPersistentStore MR_cloudURLForUbiqutiousContainer:containerID];
        NSString *contentNameKey = [self iCloudContentNameKey];
        NSDictionary *options = @{contentNameKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey,cloudURL:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey};
        NSURL *storeURL = [NSPersistentStore MR_urlForStoreName:[self localStoreName]];
//        NSURL *storeURL = [NSPersistentStore MR_urlForStoreName:[MagicalRecord defaultStoreName];
    //    [MagicalRecord cleanUp];
        DDLogiCloud(@"Resetting CoreData and iCloud named %@ at %@",containerID,storeURL);
        NSError *error;
        bool removeResult = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator removeUbiquitousContentAndPersistentStoreAtURL:storeURL options:options error:&error];
        if (removeResult == NO) {
            DDLogError(@"Could not remove iCloud Container. Reason: %@", error.localizedFailureReason);
        }
        return removeResult;
    }
```

No matter what I try, the call to removeUbiquitous... throws an error of 'Must pass in a store name'.

Any guidance on this would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo and keys and values in `options` dictionary in `resetCoreDataWithiCloud` are swapped.

In any case `storeOptions` should be the same you use to setup the store in the first place, so it's probably better to pick them up from existing store if possible, i.e:

```
// Get current store options
NSPersistentStore *store = [NSPersistentStore MR_defaultPersistentStore];
NSURL *storeURL = store.URL;
NSDictionary *storeOptions = store.options;

// Destroy CoreData stack
[MagicalRecord cleanUp];

// Delete the store
NSError *error;
BOOL isDeletedFromiCloud = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator removeUbiquitousContentAndPersistentStoreAtURL:storeURL options:storeOptions error:&error];

// Handle errors
if(isDeletedFromiCloud) {
    NSLog(@"Deleted iCloud persistent store.");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Cannot delete iCloud persistent store. Error: %@", error);
}
```

In practice `removeUbiquitousContentAndPersistentStoreAtURL` may take a while so better be called from background. If you only need it for development then it's fine from main thread too.